# opening up my app after user enabled location

Tags: android, kotlin-android

If location is disabled, I want to ask the user to enable it. For that, a dialog is displayed and user can open settings screen of the device and enable location. But after that, my app has dead. Clicking back button on the device goes just to settings and eventually home page. The only way is for me to open my app and start capturing details from zero again, which is bad experience.

Is there a way to listen to the selection of the user and if he grants permission, I continue with the data collection flow? Here is the portion that asks for user location enabling.

```
@Composable
private fun RequestEnableLocationDialog(onRequestPermissionResult: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val openSettingsLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        ) {
            onRequestPermissionResult(
                locationEnabled(context),
            )
        }

    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = { onRequestPermissionResult(false) },
        title = { Text(text = "Enable Location") },
        text = { Text(text = "You need to enable location...") },
        confirmButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    openSettingsLauncher.launch(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
                },
            ) {
                Text(text = "Open Settings")
            }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = { onRequestPermissionResult(false) },
            ) {
                Text(text = "Cancel")
            }
        },
    )
}

private fun locationEnabled(context: Context): Boolean {
    val locationManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    return LocationManagerCompat.isLocationEnabled(locationManager)
}
```

Comment: Unclear if you are following: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#workflow_for_requesting_permissions and where in your code are you checking: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#already-granted

Comment: oh let me update my question. Permission is being asked separately, if not granted already and working well.